# Check using JavaScript or C# if Java Application (NOT JAVA!) is installed on client computer

Tags: java, javascript, c#

I write project. In this project, when user click on some links - I call via my custom protocol("jpck") My Java Application(Java plugin) - and do something

So I show to User always popup when I write if you don't have a plugin  - Install Plugin

Now I want check If he has this plugin

Its need work against MAC and PC

I'm not sure if I can do that on C#, because MAC have protection from all

Comment: Have you considered Java WebStart?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your user install your plugin with an installer.

Ask this installer to write in some well defined file the location selected by user (either default location or a custom one).

Then from your program, check this well defined file.